# zipping files with the same name in different folders using 7z @listfile feature

Tags: directory, compression, duplicates, 7zip

I want to create a 7zip file containing files with the same names but in different folders using 7zip's @listfile feature. Although I have used 7zip CLI for a long time, I just cannot find the syntax to accomplish this.

My file tree looks like this (note that somefile1.html and somefile2.html occur twice each).

```
|   somefile2.html
+---dir1
|       somefile1.html
|       somefile2.html
|       
+---dir2
|       somefile3.html
|       somefile4.html
|       
\---dir3
        somefile1.html
        somefile5.html
```

Using a @listfile works fine, but I cannot figure out how to retain the directory tree in the resulting 7zip while doing that.

I have tried to the following syntax:

7z a -ir@files.txt my_compressed_file.7z

Then, given the explanations in 7zip's Windows CHM help file under syntax, I tried including the root folder, too (called 'files'):

7z a -ir@files.txt my_compressed_file.7z .\files

I get the same error in both cases:

```
Error
Duplicate filename:
somefile1.html
somefile2.html
```

Has anyone figured this one out and would care to shed some light on it?

I know how to compress files with the same names in different folders otherwise (when the folder structure is retained in the 7zip it s no problem). But this time the few files I need are spread all over the place...

Comment: This has been a HUGE bug in 7zip for many years. It's been reported many times to 7zip's authors... but they just don't seem to understand it. I avoid 7zip.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following commands for windows, using the shell and 7za (the command-line version of 7zip) could probably be adapted for other platforms; but this solved the problem for me:

1) Make a list of all the files you want to archive, including full paths, with a command like the following; suppose your command prompt is in the C:\ directory and you want to list all *.xmp files in all sub-directories on the C: drive, for archiving in the next step:

```
DIR /B /S *.xmp > XMPsToArchiveList.txt
```

2) Use XMPsToArchiveList.txt as the list file for 7za, with the -spf switch, which instructs 7za to "use fully qualified file paths:"

```
7za a -spf -ir@XMPsToArchiveList.txt allCdriveXMPs.7z
```

If all goes well, you should receive the blissful message: "Everything is OK," and see a new and proper so named .7z archive.

In my test, the resulting .7z archive has folders and sub-folders reflecting the full paths to all .xmp files, with the root folder titled "C:".

NOTES:

A) On Windows, to adapt the list command to include everything in so many directories of a given name (in so many different places), you can use e.g.:

```
DIR /S /B *_aCertainFolderNameDuplicatedAllOverTheDrive* > foldersToArchive.txt
```

B) The -spf switch was added 2011-09-16; re: http://www.7-zip.org/history.txt

Also, I tried wildcards trying to produce a list like you describe, but didn't have any luck getting all files named e.g. somefile*.txt into a list (such as archiveTheseFiles.txt). Maybe I mis-typed? Seems simple. You'll need to mess around at the prompt to find what works for you.

Finally, I don't know whether the -spf switch is available for 7z (as opposed to 7za). 7za is available yonder, in the "extras" download: http://www.7-zip.org/download.html

Comment: Thanks for some really useful insight into the 7z command line. Marking your post as the answer. This addressed a related issue I had wrt zipping up modified files, with the directory structure intact, for backup purposes. The original problem was also solved - just confirmed that. Thanks!

Comment: You can use PowerShell to generate the list file and keep relative paths instead of absolute path: `ls *.xmp -Recurse | Resolve-Path -Relative | %{$_.Substring(2)} | ac XMPsToArchiveList.txt`

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same error (Duplicate filename) while using a list file. My list file looked like this:

```
D:\SomeDir\SomeFile.txt
D:\SomeOtherDir\SomeFile.txt
```

I resolved the problem by launching 7-zip from D:\ and editing my list file to use relative rather than absolute paths:

```
SomeDir\SomeFile.txt
SomeOtherDir\SomeFile.txt
```

The resulting archive preserved the original directory structure and looked exactly as I expected.

Note: I was using 7-Zip 4.65, and this solution will not work if the files are on different drives or have a different root.

The PowerShell command line I ran was:

```
& 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' a -scsWIN logs.7z `@recentlogs.txt
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed to pack things with absolute paths, thanks. :)

Comment: This works, just remember to trim off any leading path chars ('\').

Comment: When I want to store off a project I'm working on (for example, I'm in the middle of one right now, where I tried out a number of different tactics, I've settled on one, and I'm about to strip out all of the other code, but I want to archive it with the code-as-examples) - my project is called "Mirror" (in a "Mirror" folder in D:\prog\csharp):

    cd \prog\csharp
    7za.exe a -t7z D:\prog\archives\csharp_Mirror_20151127.7z @D:\prog\bkp\Mirror\program_Mirror_backuplist.txt -mx=9 -ms=off

(The "program_Mirror_backuplist.txt" being a list of the specific files I want to back up.)

Answer (score 3):

My real directory structure was:

```
+---Release
|   |   Lib.dll
|   \--- x64
|           Lib.dll
|       
+---Definition_files
|       data_files
|       
+---x64
|       Lib.dll // Copy of the previous file (only to preserve "x64" directory")
\---Documentation
        documentation_files....
```

I used the list file:

```
 .\Release\Lib.dll // used ".\" to remove "Release" directory
 Definition_files\data_files
 Documentation\documentation_files
 x64\Lib.dll
```

Commandline:

```
7z.exe a -mx=9 -mpass=5 -r .\Packgakes\release.zip .@Lib.lst
```

This caused a duplicity error. Without "-r" there is no error.

Try to check command line for recursive scan and list of files if there really are not two files with the same destination path *(using "." in file path removes path in output)*.

Comment: This feature really needs added to the 7-zip documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Since 7z is buggy, if you insist on using 7z to compress, try using tar to create a .tar archive first then make a .tar.7z archive.

Comment: given the question mentions windows help file they might not have tar.

Answer (score 1):

Since 7-zip 9.38 beta you can select path mode: relative, full, absolute.

Comment: @AlexHall it is only GUI option in "Add to Archive" dialog window